# Chrome driver is unable to detect email field on gmail with headless mode on

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to log in to gmail with selenium webdriver.

Following code works without headless option and I can successfully login:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument(" — incognito")
loadtime = 4.0

try:
    browser = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)
except:
    browser = webdriver.Chrome('./chromedriver', chrome_options=options)

gmail_link = 'https://accounts.google.com/signin'

browser.get(gmail_link)

email = WebDriverWait(browser, loadtime).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "identifierId")))
email.send_keys('my_email')
nextButton = WebDriverWait(browser, loadtime).until(lambda x: x.find_element_by_id('identifierNext'))
nextButton.click()

password = WebDriverWait(browser, loadtime).until(
    EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@name='password']"))
)
password.send_keys('my_password')
browser.find_element_by_id("passwordNext").click()
```

But if I add the following option, it just cannot find email element and throws time out.

```
options.add_argument('--headless')
```

Before you mark this question as duplicate (I know there are many other similar questions but none of them helped me):

I would like to mention that this works for other websites, for example I can go to facebook and login with headless option. But it looks like for some reason email field is not visible for gmail with headless option.

Thus, this problem feels like gmail specific.

This is how email field on gmail looks like when inspected:
[image]

Any ideas on how to overcome this problem?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to get page source when you will run test in headless mode. It is possible, that in headless structure can be different. 
Also, please try to use different locator such as //input[@type='email'] - first make sure that there are no other inputs with type 'email'.

Comment: It's completly true the page source in headless mode is different from the non headless!

Answer (score 0):

It because in headless mode chrome use to pick the oldest version of gmail or non JS enabled version of gmail. If you go to site setting and disable the javascript to gmail then you'll get another version of gmail while revisit. So chrome used have that xpath of that older version while running in headless mode if you want to run selenium in gmail you can go for mozilla it works fine or else give user-agent to the browser while running while running in chrome headless.